# Odd Metal shader profiler results with atomic functions

Tags: ios, xcode, gpgpu, metal

I've implemented a minimal test compute shader in order to get a feel for the performance of Metal atomic functions, specifically `atomic_fetch_add_explicit` and `atomic_compare_exchange_weak_explicit` using `atomic_uint` in the `device` address space.

Running a compute kernel which runs `atomic_fetch_add_explicit` once, 307200 times, takes around 50 µs on an iPhone 12 Pro. Running `atomic_fetch_add_explicit` 10 times per thread instead takes about 650 µs, which makes sense. However, I'm confused by the Xcode shader profiler's line-by-line performance metrics:

[image: One atomic function call]

[image: Ten atomic function calls]

Blue, red and yellow mean arithmetic, synchronisation and control flow, respectively. According to [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/shader_authoring/optimizing_performance_with_the_shader_profiler), this result means the atomic function calls each take zero percent of the function's total elapsed time:

> The statistics for lines in the function body indicate the time as a percent of the function's total elapsed time.

However clearly that's not the case, as my time expenditure is multiplied roughly ten-fold as I go from one to ten calls per thread.

Is this an Xcode bug, or am I missing something here? Answers appreciated, answers with sources doubly appreciated. :)